# Limit of sequence $a_0=-1$, $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have to prove convergence and find its limit of sequnce $a_0=-1$, $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ for $n \ge 0$ where $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0; \infty)$ is continous and $f(0)=0$ and $\forall_{x>0}{f(x)<x}$. If $f(-1) = 0$ then $a_n = 0$ for $n >0$ and limit is $0$. When $f(-1) > 0 $  sequnce is decreasing and its infimum is $0$ because of function's set of values so limit is also $0$. Am I right?

Comment: Since the $a_i$ are decreasing and nonnegative for $i\ge 1$, it's easy to show convergence. But your argument that "since the lower bound of the interval is 0, the limit must be 0" is definitely not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say yes. Let $a =\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$. Since $f$ is continous we have $$a= \lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to \infty} f(a_n) = f(\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n) = f(a)$$

So $a$ is fixed point for $f$. If $a>0$ then $f(a)<a$ a contradiction, thus $a=0$.