# Fixed point of continuous function

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, fixed-points

Given a continuous function $f : [0; +\infty) \rightarrow [0; +\infty)$ such that $$\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{f(x)}x}=\frac{12}{13},$$
I have to prove that this function has a fixed point.

I noticed that $\frac{f(x)}{x} \le \frac{12}{13}$ so $f(x) \le \frac{12x}{13}$, but what to do next?

Comment: How do you conclude that $f(x)/x\le\frac{12}{13}$?

Answer (score 1):

If this $f(x)\leq {12\over 13}x $ is true then $f(x)<x$ and you can use this:

[Limit of sequence $a_0=-1$, $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461958/limit-of-sequence-a-0-1-a-n1-fa-n/2461978#2461978)

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{12}{13} x + x e^{-x}$

Answer (score 1):

- If $f(0)=0$ then $0$ is a fixed point and we are done.
- If $f(0)=a>0$ then by continuity for $\varepsilon=\frac a2,\exists \ 0<\delta<\frac a2\ \text{ st. }\ |x|\le\delta\implies |f(x)-a|<\varepsilon$

Considering both $x$ and $f(x)$ are positive quantities we can get rid of absolute values and get

$f(x)>\frac a2$ and $x<\frac a2\ $ so $\ |x|\le\delta\implies\dfrac{f(x)}{x}>1$

Similarly in infinity since $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{12}{13}<1$ then by continuity of $f$ we can find $M>\delta$ such that $x\ge M\implies \dfrac{f(x)}{x}<1$

We can now apply IVT to the continuous function $\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$ in interval $[\delta,M]$ and there is a point $x_0$ in this interval such that $\dfrac{f(x_0)}{x_0}=1\iff f(x_0)=x_0$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{f(x)}{x}}=\frac{12}{13}$$
means that $\forall \varepsilon>0$ there exists $M_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}$ such that if $x>M_\varepsilon$ then $$-\varepsilon <\frac{f(x)}{x}-\frac{12}{13}<\varepsilon$$
that is
$$\frac{12}{13}-\varepsilon <\frac{f(x)}{x}<\frac{12}{13}+\varepsilon$$
and then
$$x\left(\frac{12}{13}-\varepsilon\right) <f(x)<x\left(\frac{12}{13}+\varepsilon\right)$$
Choose $\varepsilon=\frac{2}{3}$. We have for $x>M_{\frac23}$
$$\frac{10}{13}\,x <f(x)<\frac{14}{13}\,x$$
as $f$ is continuous, for the intermediate values theorem, there exists at least one value $\bar x$ such that $f(\bar x)=\bar x$

Comment: pity this proof doesn't work for $f(x)=12x/13$ as there is no $x>M>0$ such that $f(x)=x$.

Comment: @zwim where is it stated in my proof that $M>0$?

Comment: Do you agree that your proof won't change at all if we change the domain of $f$. For instance to $[1,+\infty[$. So you end up proving something wrong. There is a flaw somewhere. It is like saying $g(x)\to 2$ so $1<g(x)<3$ so there exist $g(c)=2.5$, but it is not working for $g(x)=2$ the constant function.